# XML viewer with breadcrumb navigation

Tags: xml, ide, xmlreader, breadcrumbs

As I was working with huge nested XML files (>20k lines, up to 30 sub-trees/childs) these days, I am wondering, if there is any tool or plugin that can show me the structure of an XML file interactively as a list while clicking through it.

A familiar function is integrated in IDEs like PyCharm, where you can see the object/function/loop/.. inside that you are working or rather your cursor is placed.

I've already tried using PyCharm, Sublime Text 3 and VS Code to solve this issue, but I didn't find a solution. Any suggestion? (I'm working on Mac)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a PyCharm Plugin called [xStructure](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1867-xstructure).

It supports breadcrumb navigation.

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked with Visual Studio Code, after installing the third-party extension [XSLT/XPath for Visual Studio Code](https://deltaxml.github.io/vscode-xslt-xpath/navigation.html).

Make sure that the breadcrumbs are enabled in the settings (`CTRL+,`, then digit "breadcrumbs" in the search bar). Optionally disable them for the file path by selecting `off` under *"Breadcrumbs: File Path"*, if you only want them for the XML elements.

[image: settings]

Result:

[image: breadcrumbs]